# Impressora térmica não fiscal EPSON não funciona de forma compartilhada com USB e LPT

Tags: php, java, c#, json, impressora

Estou criando um sistema em PHP e estamos entrando na fase de impressão com impressoras térmicas não fiscais. Em principio não encontrei suporte da Epson para impressão PHP e em pesquisas encontrei o componente [mike42/escpos-php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php). Utilizando ele consegui impressões em rede com Ethernet e local com USB. Meu cliente necessita de impressão LPT em rede e também USB em rede.

O sistema rodará em tablet's e haverá um servidor de impressão, onde necessariamente **não precisa ser em PHP** pois utiliza REST com os dados de impressão passados via JSON para ele.

Minha necessidade é criar um servidor(**poderia ser em outra linguagem, sem problemas**) onde seja possível impressão de outros computadores que tenham impressoras compartilhadas com ele, mas que as impressoras sejam USB e/ou LPT.

**Obs:** Na descrição do componente [mike42/escpos-php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) está que tem suporte para impressoras compartilhadas, mas na prática não foi possível, pois aparece a mensagem: *Warning: copy(\NOME-SERVIDOR\nome-impressora): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...\escpos-php-1.5.1\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 372*.

Alguma sugestão, alguém já se deparou com situação parecida?

---

Sobre questões de permissões de arquivos, ao dar permissões na pasta PRINTERS tanto do servidor como do computador onde a impressora está instalada e compartilhada com o servidor a mensagem permanece, onde de acordo com pesquisas a mesma deveria desaparecer. Juntando este fato e o de estarmos bem no inicio da parte de impressões, por isso que não teria problema se o servidor fosse em outra linguagem, por exemplo.

---

**Agradeço pelas respostas** mas até o momento sem sucesso.

Comment: A impressora está instalada no servidor? Será que esse problema de permissão não é do computador qual a impressora está instalada? Trabalho com um sistema que envia impressões pela rede e quando o problema é permissão, se o OS é Windows nós apenas damos permissões de escrita para os usuários na pasta `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS`.

Comment: Existe o servidor de impressão e um outro computador onde a impressora está instalada e compartilhada com o servidor. Isto já foi feito tanto no servidor como no computador que a impressora está instalada mas a mensagem de "Permission denied" continua.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a questão do erro `Permission denied` creio que você pode resolver com as opções de segurança e usuários.

**Edit**

Tente fazer isso: Propriedades da impressora > Segurança > Adicionar > Avançado... > Localizar Agora > Seleciona o usuário "SERVIÇO DE REDE" > OK > OK > Marca as opções de impressão e gerenciar documentos > OK. Faça um teste.

Quando você fala em portas LPT, qualquer impressora que esteja no spooler do windows, você pode compartilhar e direcionar a porta LPT para este compartilhamento.

Ex: Impressora Epson X, nome de compartilhamento \Servidor\epsonx

execute o comando: net use LPT1 \Servidor\epsonx

a partir daí, todas as impressões enviadas para a porta LPT1 serão encaminhadas para a epson do servidor.

Comment: O comando "net use LPT1 \Servidor\epsonx" funciona mas acredito que seja erro do componente, por isso a possibilidade de utilizar outra linguagem.

Comment: "opções de segurança e usuários" -> Compartilhei toda a pasta PRINTERS e nada de resposta. Como especificamente resolveria o problema de "Permission denied"?

Comment: Com qual usuário está rodando o servidor PHP?

Comment: Usuário do windows? Estou utilizando o WampServer com usuário do Windows que tem permissões administrativas.

Comment: Sendo um serviço instalado no Windows, provável que esteja rodando com system, ou serviço de rede, tente na aba de segurança da impressora dar permissão para esses usuários, você pode fazer com o usuário Todos para teste, compartilhamento acredito que não seja o caso, afinal a impressora está no mesmo computador do servidor web, correto?

Comment: A situação é que suponhamos que exista o servidor de impressão em uma sala, mas uma impressora em outra sala (outro computador) que deve ser compartilhada com o servidor. Qualquer estação mandará o comando de impressão para o servidor junto com a impressora selecionada, e o servidor imprimirá na impressora correspondente independente que esteja instalada localmente no mesmo ou compartilhada através de outro computador.

Comment: eu não consigo simular o mesmo ambiente aqui =/ mas começaria por essa questão de permissões, considerando ainda que está em ambiente windows, e há permissões de arquivo e permissões de compartilhamento. Tente fazer a impressão com comandos pelo CMD para ver se consegue resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Vendo a linha 372 do arquivo WindowsPrintConnector.php:

`return copy($from, $to);`

Vemos que está tentando fazer uma cópia de um arquivo de um local para outro. Verifique se tem permissão de criar arquivo na pasta do caminho de destino especificado na variável `$to` e se o caminho do arquivo especificado no `$from` é válido.

Comment: Compartilhei toda a pasta PRINTERS, onde em pesquisas resolveria o problema mas nada de resposta.

Comment: Quando me referi a permissão não quis dizer compartilhamento, mas sim a permissão de segurança da pasta (direito de ver, executar, modificar). Opções: A) Em Linux rodaria um comando como chmod 777 nomedapasta. B) Em Windows seria botão direito em cima da pasta, Propriedades > Segurança > Avançadas > Localizar o usuário utilizado na hora em que roda o programa e dar Controle total da pasta, ou C) pelo php poderia criar um script com o seguinte comando: chmod('/home/path/directory/', 0777);

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.
Consegui resolver o problema dando permissão na pasta `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS`
e adicionando Users@ antes do nome da impressora ex: `smb://Users@nome_do_pc/nome_da_impressora`